How to generate xml doc from json object with nested array?
I am trying to generate xml doc from js object in env node.js. My js object likes:
{
    "root": {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "root title",
        "people": [
            {"id": 33,"name": "Bill"},
            {"id": 34,"name": "Elon"}
        ],
        "camps":[
            {"id":1,"addr":"in mountain"},
            {"id":2,"addr":"t lake"}
        ]
    }
}

the expected xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root id="12" title="root title">
    <people>
        <person id="33" name="Bill" />
        <person id="34" name="Elon" />
    </people>
    <camps>
        <camp id="1" addr="in mountain"/>
        <camp id="2" addr="at lake"/>
    </camps>
</root>

I have tried some libs, their result likes below. They all split array into multiple elements with excessive wrapping. That leads to losing the hierachical relations and the result looks illogical.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <id>12</id>
  <title>root title</title>
  <people>
    <id>33</id>
    <name>Bill</name>
  </people>
  <people>
    <id>34</id>
    <name>Elon</name>
  </people>
  <camps>
    <id>1</id>
    <addr>In mountant</addr>
  </camps>
  <camps>
    <id>1</id>
    <addr>At lake</addr>
  </camps>
</root>


No off-the-shelf json-to-xml converter (or xml-to-json for that matter) will ever produce exactly the xml that you want.
Try XSLT 3.0:
<xsl:variable name="json" select="json-doc('input.json')"/>
<root id="{$json?root?id}" title="{$json?root?title}">
  <people>
     <xsl:for-each select="$json?root?people?*">
       <person id="{?id}" name="{?name}"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </people>
  <camps>
     <xsl:for-each select="$json?root?camps?*">
       <camps id="{?id}" addr="{?addr}"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </camps>
</root>

XSLT 3.0 is available in node.js via [disclaimer: my company's product] SaxonJS.
XQuery 3.0 would be another possibility.

you are right, No off-the-shelf available. I have to write a module from scratch using string manipulation approach. About XSLT, I am short of understanding.  The doc here( https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) requires considerable courage to be stduied. In spite of that, from the abstract of MDN doc(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT), I think your answer might be the ultimate answer.

Yes, XSLT does have a learning curve. However, it is extremely powerful and should be part of every XML programmer's kitbag.
